# Is $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_+: x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ bijective?

Tags: functions

I'm pretty sure it's not bijective since the negative values of the domain have no corresponding value in the codomain but it does qualify as surjective since every value in the codomain has values in the domain but also as injective since values in the domain correspond to no more than one value in the codomain unless I'm misunderstanding something. If not, then what would this function be classified as?

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is not defined on $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function (and question) is ill-defined: $f(x)$ is not defined for negative values.

Discussing whether it is injective, surjective, or bijective is entirely irrelevant -- it's not even a function.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I disagree, @ThomasAndrews. It's exactly what's needed to answer the question.

Comment: I've seen the example f:R+ -> R: -> x^2 been used as an example of a function that is injective but not surjective. Isn't this not a function either since all negative values of the codomain aren't defined?   Edit: my bad a function is define by its domain so it can have parts of the codomain be undefined and still be a function but not the other way around? @PrincessEev

Comment: @UnripeMango A function must have exactly one value at each point in the domain. $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x^2$ is a function since every positive number has a square. The "unused" values in the codomain just mean it's not surjective.

Comment: @aschepler so the definition of injectivity being that "values in the domain must have no more than one value in the codomain" means that a function cannot have domain values with less than one point in the codomain?

Comment: The definition of function means there are no domain values with less than (or more than) one point in the codomain.